# Can somebody suggest me what is wrong with this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join, where-clause

select met.metno , eps.sn , el.ed
    from el
    inner join met on eps.sn=met.sn
    inner join eps
    on el.epid=eps.epid
    where el.etid=1002
    and el.ed>'2017-01-03'
    and el.ed<'2018-07-05'

Comment: Why is this off topic? It has an answer which I think is correct. The formatting can be improved but that's a simple fix.

Answer (score 2):

You have an additional `inner join` after the where clause.  Do the joins first (`FROM`) then the `WHERE`